# Query Between Date Range Mysql Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query it only show the schedule today
my problem is the range of the schedule

| datetime_start | datetime_end |
| --- | --- |
| 8/26/22 | 8/28/22 |
| 8/25/22 | 8/28/22 |
| 8/26/22 | 8/26/22 |

it will only show this data

| datetime_start | datetime_end |
| --- | --- |
| 8/26/22 | 8/28/22 |
| 8/26/22 | 8/26/22 |

but i need also to show the 8/25 because it ends on 8/28/22

This is my sample code

```
SELECT schedule_list.reserved_by, schedule_list.schedule_remarks,
schedule_list.datetime_start, schedule_list.datetime_end, assembly_hall.room_name 
FROM schedule_list  inner join assembly_hall  on assembly_hall.id = schedule_list.assembly_hall_id
                     
WHERE  curdate() between date(datetime_start) AND date(datetime_end) 
and schedule_list.assembly_hall_id=$room_id ORDER BY datetime_start ASC
```

i dont know what seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curdate() returns date as 'YYYY-MM-DD' (string) or as YYYYMMDD (numeric)

Please use date_format to change the date format in order to use curdate()

```
curdate() between DATE_FORMAT(datetime_start, "%Y-%m-%d") AND DATE_FORMAT(datetime_end, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

First check what date return `curdate()` what I see is when you post it is 8/26/2022 so 8/25/22 is out of range